# Embed Video with Live Controls into Interactive Shiny Environment

Tags: r, video, shiny

I'm looking for a way to do the following using the Shiny package in R Studio:

- Prompt user to select video file from the computer inside main window
- Video file then opens in main window with controls (play, pause, etc.)

I've seen posts that discuss how to embed videos from websites, but I've never seen a post discuss how to select video files from your computer AND then open them with live controls within the main window.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its quite easy to add a video. To do so please structure your app like so:

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})
```

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$video(id="video2", type = "video/mp4",src = "SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4", controls = "controls")
  )
)
```

**www** - this is where your video is, here I have `.mp4` format video, downloaded from http://www.sample-videos.com/

[image]